# Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: php, postgresql

Почему-то возникает ошибка при вставке json в базу:

```
LINE 1: ...DATE tickets_cache SET (data, data_hash, date) = ('{&quot;success...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token &quot;&lt;&quot; is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {&quot;success&quot;: true, &quot;data&quot;:
```

Ошибка возникает крайне редко и в 99.8% случаев json вставляется корректно.

Код вставки данных в базу:

```
$query = "UPDATE tickets_cache SET (data, data_hash, date) = ('{$new_response}', '{$new_hash}', '{$next_day}') WHERE url_hash = '{$link_hash}'";
```

Предварительно перед передачей JSON экранируется функцией `pg_escape_string`.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может всё же стоит использовать подготовленные запросы? И пусть сам драйвер экранирует данные

Answer (score 0):

Потому что json вы передаёте неверный. Не может быть:

```
{&quot;success&quot;: ...
```

Должно быть

```
{"success": ...
```

Это не имеет никакого отношения ни к экранированию ни к подготовленным запросам, которые обеспечивают корректное представление при передаче данных от приложения к базе. Типы данных json и jsonb валидируют сам пришедший текст - и это обязан быть корректный JSON. У вас JSON приведён некорректный.